# Font style and size differences in some Linux browsers

Tags: linux, fonts

Default fonts on my site are defined in an external stylesheet as:

```
body { font-family: Arial; font-size:62.5%;}
```

This works fine in Windows and Mac.

To test my site I installed Linux Mint 13 (Mate) and loaded a selection of browsers from the Repository. I made two installations on separate PC’s. I left all browser settings as their defaults.

Firefox, Opera, Konqueror and Reconq displayed my pages as expected.

Web (Epiphany) overrides the default font style (i.e. it is not Arial) and also displays too large a font size.

Midori displays too large a font size. (installed in windows, midori displays the correct font size).

I believe Web (Epiphany) is designed principally for the GNOME desktop environment and maybe this is a factor or do I need to design differently for these two browsers to make them display the fonts correctly in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some distributions of Linux don't include the Arial font. I added Liberation Sans as an alternative font and this seems to be okay.

I don't understand however why some of the browsers didn't need this. Unless they include the font with the browser or accurately map some alternative?